# Cayley Salmon Theorem assumptions

Tags: euclidean-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

I know that the Cayley salmon theorem is defined as a smooth cubic surface in CP^3 contains 27 lines but what are the assumptions of this theorem?

Comment: Begin by googling, then come back with a more precise question.

Comment: Let be an irreducible polynomial also being non-empty? I don't understand what google give it doesn't seem like set assumptions.  I know that lines in CP^3 are given by a pair of equations such as [SY+tW, Y, uY+vW, W] where x=sY+tW wand z= uY+vW? Is that the assumption?@JeanMarie

Comment: I am sorry, I have worked on projective space but I don't know much about this cubic surface. I think that the misunderstanding between us is about what you call "assumptions". I would call them "definitions".

Comment: That's okay. I'm just going to go with what I think is the closest to an assumption. Thank you anyway !

Comment: @EvanSwan92 Are you still interested in an answer to this question?